# Angular $q.all returns null for all promises resolved

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3CnOIywZuJRtcY7XseU4?p=preview) I have a `$q.all` function that resolves two promises. Still, the function returns null when I am resolving with a value in both cases. What's wrong with this code?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,$q) {

            var promises = [];

            promises.push(function(){
                var defer = $q.defer();
                var val1 = "aaa";
                defer.resolve(val1);
                return defer.promise;
            });

            promises.push(function(){
                var defer = $q.defer();
                var val2 = "bbb";
                defer.resolve(val2);
                return defer.promise;
            });


            $q.all(promises).then(function(responses) { 
              $scope.responses = responses;
          });
});
```

Comment: Your `promises` is an array of functions and not promises. `promises.push(function ()` <==== that is adding a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this,

```
promises.push(function(){
  var defer = $q.defer();
  var val1 = "aaa";
  defer.resolve(val1);
  return defer.promise;
}());

promises.push(function(){
  var defer = $q.defer();
  var val2 = "bbb";
  defer.resolve(val2);
  return defer.promise;
}());
```

You only defined the functions, but you have to invoke them using,

```
function () {
  // body
}();  <-- note the '()'
```

Confirmed working in plunker.